# Similarity between two complex strings - excluding Levenshtein Distance

Tags: c#, string, similarity

I'm new on Stak Overflow so I hope to be clear and correct.

So, I have a problem: in input I have two strings which are Registry Key. These strings have the user' SID in. As we already know, each SID is different from the others.

For example:
String 1: `Computer\HKEY_USERS\**SID 1**\SomethingHere\SomethingHere`

String 2: `Computer\HKEY_USERS\**SID 2**\SomethingHere\SomethingHere`

SID1 and SID2 are a set of numbers, letters and "-".

The keys are almost the same. How can I establish that the two strings are similar in C#?
I've already used **Levenshtein Distance** but it works fine on short strings.
For example, the distance between string 1 and string 2 where `string 1 == string2 = my first name` is `0`, but the same distance between the registry keys with SIDs are `28`.

Comment: Are you saying that the two `SomethingHere` parts are the same in both the strings? It's not `SomethingHere\SomethingElseHere` in one string vs. `SomethingReallyElseHere\AltogetherDifferent`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is for example. The strings are the complete registry key but with two different SIDs

Comment: Could you simply replace the SIDs first? `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=Computer\\HKEY_USERS\\)[^\\]+(?=\\)", "<SID>")`

Comment: I understand that, I'm just asking if the two parts after the SIDs are the same in both, or if they're different as well. For instance, are you comparing `Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-2-3\Control Panel\Accessibility` vs. `Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-2-4-59875987532\Control Panel\Accessibility` or vs. `Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-2-4-59875987532\International\Geo` as examples of what I'm asking about.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen.
yes, string 1 is Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-2-3\Control Panel\Accessibility and string 2 is Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-2-4-59875987532\Control Panel\Accessibility